# How to change width of colorpick in fieldset ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I want to change colorpick width when change width of fieldset.
I tried use `maxWidth`, but it not helped:

```
{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: __('colors'),
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        layout: 'vbox',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            align: 'center'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                defaults: {
                    // anchor: '100%',
                    maxWidth: 140,
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    padding: '0 5px 0 5px'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'colorfield',
                        fieldLabel: __('email_heading'),
                        bind: '{headerColor}'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'colorfield',
                        fieldLabel: __('email_content_color'),
                        bind: '{contentColor}'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                defaults: {
                    // anchor: '50%',
                    maxWidth: 140,
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    padding: '0 5px 0 5px'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'colorfield',
                        fieldLabel: __('email_btn_text_color'),
                        bind: '{textBtnColor}'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'colorfield',
                        fieldLabel: __('email_btn_color'),
                        bind: '{colorBtn}'
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```

When screen small fieldset overlaps my colorpick and not change width:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set `width: 320` on the parent `xtype: 'fieldset'` node... in order not to have it's items cut off alike that. if that does not help, try the same with the parent `xtype: 'form'` node. the property `maxWidth` only defines the maximum width such a node can have, not the actual width.

Comment: Thank you, but it not helped(